# Upgrading to Windows 8.1 from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, upgrade

My PC is running with 2 hard drives, a 128gb SSD and a 1TB HDD. My Windows 7 install is on the SSD but I installed Steam and all my games on the HDD. When I ran the Windows Upgrade Assistant, it reported that I needed to reinstall Steam and my games after the upgrade. So my question is, after the upgrade, if my Steam and game files are left on the HDD, do I still need to reinstall them altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8, then 8.1. I have not had to reinstall Steam at all. I believe the Windows Upgrade Assistant simply informs you that you may need to reinstall applications because it can't quite work out if it will still work after the upgrade.

If you're really worried, you can [back up Steam games](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8794-yphv-2033).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite how Steam handles its games... but, it looks like Steam doesn't offer different versions for different Windows OSs (based on a quick look over their website). You could probably just pull the HDD, install 8.1, and then put back in the HDD. If it doesn't work, well, what's the worst that could happen? You'd just have to reinstall Steam and your games, and you'd be happily playing again!